# Concatenate cells with space in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

```
Public Function concat(r As Range) As String
    concat = ""
    For Each rr In r
        concat = concat & rr.Value
    Next rr
End Function
```

I have embedded above function which works well, however need to resolve following concern:

I have 700 individual English words (from A1 to A700) which I want to combine in to one single cell (by using =concat(A1:A700) but with space after each individual words. Mean to say at present when I am using said function then there is no space appearing between individual words which is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel silly writing this

```
Public Function concat(r As Range) As String
    concat = ""
    For Each rr In r
        concat = concat & rr.Value & " "            
    Next rr
    concat = Trim(concat) 'Removes leading and trailing spaces from a string.
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Append the space after `rr.Value`

```
Public Function concat(r As Range) As String
    concat = ""
    For Each rr In r
        concat = concat & rr.Value & " "
    Next rr
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each rr In r
        concat = concat & rr.Value & " "
Next rr
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but there is a subtle point that none of the other answers picked up on. The OP asked for a space between words and did not state that a space after the last word was either acceptable or desired. Moving the assignment of the space in front of the rr.Value instead of after means that the final string ends with the last character of the last word, instead of with a space. It is not difficult to address a trailing space but in some instances this could be significant.

```
Public Function concat(r As Range) As String
    concat = ""
    For Each rr In r
        if not isnull(concat) then
            ' most of the time concat is not null, so use that to 
            ' identify the route to take because of this evaluation
            concat = concat & " " & rr.Value
        else               
            ' when concat is null, avoid padding with the space
            concat = rr.Value
        end if
    Next rr
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the formatting edit @FelixSFD. I will edit the code in just a moment to prevent prepending a space when concat is still null.

Answer (score 0):

I modded Thinkingcap's solution a little bit.  Thanks for the help.

```
Public Function concat(r As Range) As String
    concat = ""
    For Each rr In r
        If rr.Value = "" Then GoTo Skip
        concat = concat & rr.Value & " "
Skip:
    Next rr
    concat = Trim(concat) 'Removes leading and trailing spaces from a string.
End Function
```